# OpenLDAP Consumer Replica

Tags: ubuntu, openldap

I have a Cluster OpenLDAP setup with 2 OpenLDAP servers running syncrepl on config and data, providing LDAP authentication to specific systems running various embedded OS.

Now I was asked to add a Consumer replica with a subset of users and groups from the Cluster setup, running on a remote site.

I used the Ubuntu documentation as a reference.
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-ldap-replication

Provider and Consumer have the indexes needed according to the documentation.

SyncRepl configuration on Consumer.

dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcSyncrepl
olcSyncrepl: rid=123
provider=ldap://DNSNAME.Cluster.Ldap
bindmethod=simple
binddn="cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=test"
credentials=secret
searchbase="dc=ldap,dc=test"
schemachecking=on
type=refreshOnly
interval=00:00:05:00

The issue is that changes to group membership do not get synchronized before I restart the SLAPD service.

I have tried with a filter, permissions on what the Consumer can read on Cluster, or just replicate the entire database.

Any pointers to what I can have missed ?

Comment: I know that the connection is unsecure, TLS will be implemented when the replication is working, to be sure there are limited error posibilites.

I have waited hours, the the replication to update the group memberships, but the only thing that can initiate the update are a restart of the SLAPD.


Debug log have been runnung from day 1, but I cant se why the group update will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the problem you asked about, however, your posted question has your sending a cleartext password across whatever you link is between the provider and the consumer, and it looks like you're doing so with what's probably olcRoot. Might want to get at least some TLS on that.

---

Either use `type=refreshAndPersist` or wait out your set `interval` (looks to be 5 minutes).
You might want to set a `retry` as a general measure, but especially if you do end up using refreshAndPresist.

---

If you're not already logging it's past time to start.

```
`/etc/rsyslog.d/slapd.conf`

# Don't forget to restart rsyslog after adding this.
# You'll also need an appropriate olcLogLevel. E.g., olcLoglevel: config sync
local4.*        /var/log/syslog
```